# Solution of a hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I am thinking the differential equation
$(1+e^x)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+(2+e^x-\delta)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$.

Here $\delta$ is a parameter I want it to approaches to zero. I think this can be transformed into the hypergeometric differential equation

$z(1-z)y''(z)+(1-\delta)zy'(z)-y=0$. Does it have a solution?

Also, since I am interested in the regime $x<0$, thus when $|x|$ is large enough, it seems that we can get an approximation by ignoring the terms with $e^{x}$ in the differential equation. Can we figure out when this approximation is valid?

Thanks

Comment: y[x] == (E^x)^((-2 - d - Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d])/2) Hypergeometric2F1[(-(Sqrt[d] (Sqrt[d] + Sqrt[4 + d])))/2, (-2 - d - Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d])/2, 1 - Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d], -E^x] Subscript[c, 1] + (E^x)^((-2 - d + Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d])/2) Hypergeometric2F1[(-2 - d + Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d])/2, (-d + Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d])/2, 1 + Sqrt[d] Sqrt[4 + d], -E^x] Subscript[c, 2]

Answer (score 1):

Let $2-\delta=-k-1/k$ (so $\sqrt\delta=\sqrt k+1/\sqrt k$) and $z(t)=z(-e^{-x})=y(x)$. Then in the $(z,t)$ plane we have the hypergeometric differential equation
$$t(1-t)z''(t)-t(k+1/k+1)z'(t)-z(t)=0$$
with $(a,b,c)=(k,1/k,0)$. Expand at $t=\infty$ for the two fundamental solutions:
$$z(t)=At^{-k}{_2F_1}(k,1+k,1+k-1/k,1/t)+Bt^{-1/k}{_2F_1}(1/k,1+1/k,1+1/k-k,1/t)$$
In terms of $x$ and $y$ this becomes
$$y(x)=Ae^{xk}{_2F_1}(k,1+k,1+k-1/k,-e^x)+Be^{x/k}{_2F_1}(1/k,1+1/k,1+1/k-k,-e^x)$$
As $x\to-\infty$ the main argument of the hypergeometric functions involved goes to $0$, so said functions may be approximated by $1$:
$$y(x)\approx Ae^{xk}+Be^{x/k}$$
This matches the solution of the original differential equation minus the $e^x$ terms (which can be solved elementarily), so the approximation is valid regardless of $\delta$.

Comment: Hi Parcly, sorry for the late reply. I think this expansion is what I want. But I have a small question about the singularities. Based on Wikipedia, $\infty$ is a singularity. But when we take x to $-\infty$, $t \to -\infty$. Is $-\infty$ also a singularity?(Just as $\infty$)